# Working with csv data for web development

Tags: python, html, django, csv

I am trying to build a webpage which will display some data from a csv file. Preferably, I want to be able to load the csv data, and then able to select from the data and plot it.
I am new to web-development, and have set-up a simple site using django. However, I cannot see the easiest way to access the data from the csv files in the html/js files. Are there any existing frameworks by which this can be done- dash seems like a potential candidate but I am unsure. Alternatively, it seems that I may be able to load csv files via the static files directory in django, but this also seems like a lot of hassle.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You might create a django view that reads the data with the csv module and displays it in a table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer consist of two parts. First part is backend and second one is frontend. Please take a look at the options offered in them and select the one that is most convenient for you.

## Backend

***File storing***

Because you use Django then I see such ways to achieve your goal:

1. Save csv file in static files (as you noted above). If you have just a few csv files and no need to update them, then this option may be good. But if not, see other options.
2. If you will manage many files and you need to store their data, then best option is to create model with [FileField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#filefield) in it. Just save your csv into this field and then extract when you need it.
3. If you don't need to save data and just show this data on the page, then you can add form on page with file uploading. And then parse this file (and not forgetting, of course, the precautions).

***File parsing***

How to parse csv file you can read at [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

But you can use [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) or even [Django Pandas](https://django-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) for that purpose. These libraries will help you avoid the many problems that may arise during data processing.

You can use [Jupyter Notebook](https://jupyter.org/) for testing the interaction before moving everything into Django.

Also you can create auxiliary class that helps you to interact with the desired fields.

## Frontend

There are many libraries that you can use. I suggest to look in the direction of [Bokeh](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/index.html). You can find tutorials how to connect bokeh with django ([one](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/notes/bokeh-interactive-visualization-library-use-graph-with-django-template/), [two](https://hackernoon.com/integrating-bokeh-visualisations-into-django-projects-a1c01a16b67a)). And bokeh also works with jupyter that I mentioned above.

If you don't want to bother then look to [Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/) which has a low entry threshold.

You can use Dash if you see that it is exactly what you need from the description.

Or look at any of the other javascript libraries for visualization, you don’t have to get hung up on python libs.